# ElasticSearch script_lang not supported [groovy]

Tags: java, elasticsearch, groovy

I'm upgrading ElasticSearch from 1.2 to 2.2. I dug successfully through quite some breaking API changes. I found that groovy scripts in script_score don't work. I enabled dynamic scripting by turning on

```
script.inline=true
script.indexed=true
```

I included groovy-all 2.4.6. I also added jna and mustache to not see any exceptions when the embedded ElasticSearch starts.

The configuration of my embedded server is:

```java
        ESLoggerFactory.setDefaultFactory(new Slf4jESLoggerFactory());
        Settings settings = Settings.builder()
                .put("node.name" ,getName())
                .put("path.home", "/tmp/elastic-search/home")
                .put("path.shared_data", /tmp/elastic-search")
                .put(IndexMetaData.SETTING_NUMBER_OF_SHARDS, "1")
                .put(IndexMetaData.SETTING_NUMBER_OF_REPLICAS, "0")
                .put("action.auto_create_index", "0")
                .put("index.gateway.type", "none")
                .put("script.inline", true)
                .put("script.indexed", true)
                .put("action.destructive_requires_name", false)
                .build();

        node = nodeBuilder().clusterName(clusterName).settings(settings).node();
```

Then I execute a query which contains a snippet under function_score/functions which looks loke:

```json
        "filter" : {
          "exists" : {
            "field" : "transactionCount"
          }
        },
        "script_score" : {
          "script" : {
            "inline" : "doc['transactionCount'].value/10.0"
          }
        }
```

The execution throws:

```
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryParsingException: script_score the script could not be loaded
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: script_lang not supported [groovy]
    at  org.elasticsearch.script.ScriptService.getScriptEngineServiceForLang(ScriptService.java:211)
```

When debugging I saw in ScriptModule that the script engine for Groovy is missing. Only the native and the mustache ones are present.

Any tip is very welcome:)

Comment: Where did you include the groovy-all JAR?

Comment: and did you include lang-groovy-2.2.0.jar ? groovy has been removed from the core jar, it's now a module

Comment: We use Maven so I added it as a dependency.I'll try tomorrow with lang-groovy and also Jeremie B answer.Will keep you posted.Thanks!

Comment: If your local elasticsearch dir lacks the module lang-groovy, download the tarball from the Elastic Search website, copy it from the extracted tarball, and restart Elastic Search.

Comment: To confuse things there is: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-lang-groovy in version 2.2.0 which is deprecated - not needed from ES 1.4. So thanks for pointing me on the right track. What I'm looking for is org.elasticsearch.module:lang-groovy 2.2.0. I cannot find it on the maven repo but I found it in the local ES installation so I can try to get it into the embedded one.

Comment: Found it:) http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/elasticsearch/module/lang-groovy/2.2.0/ And the solution works! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In ElasticSearch 2.2, the scripts engines have been externalized: they are now plugins, which you can install on demand. Plugins are discovered by scanning the `plugins` folder.

If you use an embedded node, you have two choices:

- Use this plugins folder, and copy the lang-groovy-2.2.0.jar in this folder
- Explicitly register the Groovy plugins when you create your node

In my project, I use the 2nd case: ElasticSearch is embedded in an osgi container, and I wanted to discover the plugins through a classical classpath scanning. To do this kind of things, you must override `Node`:

```
class ConfigurableNode extends Node {
  public ConfigurableNode(Settings settings, Collection<Class<? extends Plugin>> classpathPlugins) {
    super(InternalSettingsPreparer.prepareEnvironment(preparedSettings, null), 
      Version.CURRENT, 
      classpathPlugins);
  }
}
```

and you create your node with :

```
Node node = new ConfigurableNode(nodeBuilder()
  .clusterName(clusterName)
  .settings(settings)
  .getSettings(), 
    Arrays.asList(GroovyPlugin.class));
```

It's not pretty but I didn't find a method more elegant in v2.2

Comment: Just a short clarification. One needs to add as a dependency: http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/elasticsearch/module/lang-groovy/2.2.0/

Comment: Don't forget to call node.start() - this is what NodeBuilder.node() internally does. Took me some hours to find that...

Comment: good to be aware that Elastic official position since 2016 is to totally drop the support for embedded elastic usage: https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-the-server

Answer (score 0):

Add the below 3 entries in the elasticsearch.yml file. It will resolve the issue.

```
index.max_result_window: 2147483647 
script.engine.groovy.inline.aggs: on 
script.engine.groovy.inline.search: on
```